# kerberoasting on a standard user domain account

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, kerberoasting

Kerberoasting is an attack against domain service accounts.

I have a custom Windows service written in C#. This service is running on a Windows server. This server is a member of the Active Directory domain.

The service is running as a domain standard user (service "Logon" tab).
The "Service Principal Name" of this user is blank.

Is it possible to run a Kerberoasting attack against this user with a blank SPN?